SSH to EC2 times out, but other instances in the same security group are reachable
Something really weird happened to one of my EC2 istances.
So I have a security group and a bunch of instances associated with that group. I can SSH into all of those intances.
I created a new instance and put it into the same SG. The instace has public IPv4 and it is reacachable via port 80 for example.
But I cannot connect to it via SSH. I get a timeout.
If I modify the SG and allow SSH from 0.0.0.0/0 I can connect.
So the question is, why old instances in the same SG are reachable whilst the new one is not. Old instances do not have any other SGs assigned.

Your question can't be answered with the information provided. If you want help you will need to provide precise information about configurations of instances and security groups. One thing to note is two resources in a security group can't automatically communicate, you need a self-referential security group - ie the security group ingress section must specify itself as an allowed source of traffic.

To be fair I don't know what else could be provided here :)
If we abstract from specifics, the problem is following: the same SG, two instances with the same settings (they are even launched by the same launch template). You can connect to one and cannot connect to another. But if you allow connections from everywhere (0.0.0.0) in SG, you can connect to both instances.

If this was my instance I would start with basics, and if you want a solution provide screenshots of these. Internet gateway, route table, VPC and subnet, security groups (screenshot of instance showing what it has and of the SG, in and out), NACLs for the subnet. Once I validated that was ok I would look at the instance firewall and instance configuration in general. I'd also create a new instance in the same SG and different SGs to see if they were accessible.

The fact that it works when allowing 0.0.0.0/0 indicates that the timeout is caused by the security group -- everything else is configured correctly. How are you connecting to the instance -- are you using ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4 or are you going via EC2 Instance Connect? Also, here's a tip... If you open 0.0.0.0/0 and connect, then disconnect and connect again, it will tell you the IP address used in the previous connection. This is the IP address that your request is coming from, and it should be added to the security group.

@JohnRotenstein yep, like that ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@1.2.3.4. EC2 Instance Connect works regardless of adding 0.0.0.0/0. I also think that it is security group, but I can connect to other instances, that's why it is really weird

I'm not familiar with EC2, but general ssh trouble-shooting scenario is to run both sides (client ssh and server sshd) in debug mode (ssh -vvv and sshd -d3 )
Can you temporarily shutdown ec2 service listening on port 80 and try to run an extra ssh deamon instance in ec2 on port 80 instead of standard port 22?
Something like /usr/sbin/sshd -d -d -d -p80
and connect to it from your client with ssh -vvv -p80
This will at least isolate the problem purely to SG configuration

As I said, I can connect if I add 0.0.0.0 into SG.
But I can connect to old instances even without such modification to SG.
So it is definitely SG blocking me by the looks of it, but I cannot explain why it does not happen to old instances

Usually Port 80 is allocated for webserver like apache and nginx. Please check your server with port 80, that might give you some idea.
netstat -tuln | grep 80
lsof -i :80
And also for ssh you've to make a port 22 open. SSH default port is 22
